# Linear Regression in R without names of column

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm

I have dataframe with unknown the number of columns and each column have different speific names. And i want to do lineare regression between first column and the others no using name of columns. Hoe i can do it?

For example, dataset of mtcars

```
fit1 <- lm(mtcars$mpg ~ ., mtcars)
```

but i want to use mtcars$mpg

Thank for your any help!

Comment: `fit1 <- lm(mtcars[,1] ~ ., mtcars)` ?

Comment: ok, but if i want to do  fit2 <- lm((fit1$residuals)^2 ~ mtcars[, 2:ncol(mtcars)] , mtcars) , i get error Error in  model.frame.default(formula = (fit1$residuals)^2 ~ mtcars[, 2:ncol(mtcars)],  :
 wrong (list) type of variables 'mtcars[, 2:ncol(mtcars)]'

Comment: That's a different question - your question specifically say "between first column and others", and Ryan Morton told you how to do that. You could also edit the data argument to exclude columns you don't want, e.g. `I(fit1$resisuals^2) ~ ., data = mtcars[, -1]`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source might be intimidating but is informative. Once you parse through `lm` after all of the `model.matrix` and other massaging, you'll see that it makes a call to `lm.fit`. If you look at the help, after the caution that it ***should usually _not_ be used directly unless by experienced users***, you can see what is going on by debugging it and seeing how `lm` is calling `lm.fit`.

```
debugonce(lm.fit)
lm(mtcars$mpg ~ mtcars$cyl, mtcars)
# debugging in: lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...)

# Browse[2]> 
head(x)
#                   (Intercept) mtcars$cyl
# Mazda RX4                   1          6
# Mazda RX4 Wag               1          6
# Datsun 710                  1          4
# Hornet 4 Drive              1          6
# Hornet Sportabout           1          8
# Valiant                     1          6

# Browse[2]> 
head(y)
#         Mazda RX4     Mazda RX4 Wag        Datsun 710    Hornet 4 Drive 
#              21.0              21.0              22.8              21.4 
# Hornet Sportabout           Valiant 
#              18.7              18.1 

# Browse[2]>
c    
# Call:
# lm(formula = mtcars$mpg ~ mtcars$cyl, data = mtcars)
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)   mtcars$cyl  
#      37.885       -2.876
```

From this it appears that `y` is simply a vector of the response variable (`mtcars$mpg`), and `x` is a matrix with all of the explanatory variables plus a leading column, the intercept. (I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to add additional columns.)

Calling it directly might look like:

```
mod <- lm.fit(cbind(Intercept = 1, mtcars$cyl), mtcars$mpg)
str(mod)
# List of 8
#  $ coefficients : Named num [1:2] 37.88 -2.88
#   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "Intercept" ""
#  $ residuals    : num [1:32] 0.37 0.37 -3.58 0.77 3.82 ...
#  $ effects      : Named num [1:32] -113.65 -28.6 -3.7 0.71 3.82 ...
#   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:32] "Intercept" "" "" "" ...
#  $ rank         : int 2
#  $ fitted.values: num [1:32] 20.6 20.6 26.4 20.6 14.9 ...
#  $ assign       : NULL
#  $ qr           :List of 5
#   ..$ qr   : num [1:32, 1:2] -5.657 0.177 0.177 0.177 0.177 ...
#   .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#   .. .. ..$ : NULL
#   .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "Intercept" ""
#   ..$ qraux: num [1:2] 1.18 1.02
#   ..$ pivot: int [1:2] 1 2
#   ..$ tol  : num 1e-07
#   ..$ rank : int 2
#   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "qr"
#  $ df.residual  : int 30
```

One difference is that the output from `lm()` is of class `"lm"`, whereas the output from `lm.fit` is a `"list"`. Again, looking at the source of `lm`, you can see that it takes the output from `lm.fit` and applies a class and some other properties to the list. (These properties are often used by aesthetics like `summary` but also perhaps by other helper functions.)

Simply assign a class will improve the console-printing of it, though you'll need to test to see if your follow-on calculations/analysis require having these properties and class applied.

```
class(mod) <- "lm"
mod
# Call:
# NULL
# Coefficients:
# Intercept             
#    37.885     -2.876
```

Caveat Emptor: there are several cleaning and massaging steps in `lm` that are being completely bypassed here. By using this function, you are removing the "safety" of the user-intended wrapper function.